# Null point exception when making the asynctask call only if the json object is not null

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have activity which is calling own asynctask class to get data to load through a API call. In activity `onCreat()`, I'm calling aynctask as shown below,

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pickup_activity);


    if (!dataDelivery.isEmpty()) {         //line 77

        new PickupAsyncTask(getBaseContext(), new OnTaskCompleted() {

            @Override
            public void onTaskCompleted(JSONArray responseJson) {

                Constants.dataDelivery = responseJson.toString();

                loaddata();
                System.out.println("dataDelivery");
            }
        }).execute();
    }

    loaddata();

}

public void loaddata() {

    dataDelivery = Constants.getDataDelivery();

    try {

        JSONArray dataArray = new JSONArray(dataDelivery);
        for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); ++i) {

            JSONObject object = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);

            if (!pickupOutlet.contains(object.getString("OutletName")))
                pickupOutlet.add(object.getString("OutletName"));
        }
        findViewById(R.id.loadingPanel).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then the `jsonresponse` will be loaded to a `Constants` object so that I can use it in below shown load method,

I want to make the asynctask call only if the `dataDelivery` is empty. If not it should call the asynctask. So i tried as shown below and it ended up giving this exception.

My problem is how can I use the if condition properly.

[image]

Comment: What is at line number 77 in `ActivityPickup.java` ?

Comment: Post `ActivityPickup.java` file and point out line number `77`

Comment: put your async class code if you can to help you in better way.

Comment: line 77 is where im having the if condition if (!dataDelivery.isEmpty()) {

Comment: add this line `dataDelivery = Constants.getDataDelivery();` at line 76

Comment: @Scion of Ikshvaku that perfectly worked :)